# How to run MS Excel 2007 from a batch file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, batch-file

I can't find a proper *.exe for Excel in the usual places:

- "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office
- "c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\excel.exe"

Does anybody know where I would find the Excel executable for a Windows Vista machine? For that matter, also invoke Excel to open an existing *.xls file using a batch file?

Incidentally, the Shortcut for Excel shows "target:" to be

> Microsoft Office Professional Hybrid 2007

Comment: If your Windows install is 64-bit then Excel.exe will be in "<drive>:\Program Files (x86)\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line to your batch file:

- START "name of spreadsheet.xls"

This will use the default file association to open the file.  If you need a specific version though, then you'll need to find the appropriate .EXE file which might be under a sub-directory called "Common" or "Common files" which should be somewhere under "C:/Program Files/" or "C:/Program Files (x86)/" (stuff is often scattered between both of these as applications are slowly transitioning from 32-bit to 64-bit).

Depending on the default file assocation will ensure that your batch file is portable, so you should prefer to use this approach if you can.

Comment: Note that if your file name needs quotes due to spaces or shell metacharacters, you'll need an empty set of quotes first: `start "" "file name with spaces.xls"`

Comment: I note that invoking Microsoft Word occurs with the following string on my Vista 64-bit machine: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe"**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start excel on its own, you can use.

```
  Start Excel
```

You should be able to find the exact path by opening a command prompt and typing

```
 reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe"
```

Comment: This seems like a really good solution to me, which certainly also is in keeping with the spirit of being portable (although it may only be limited to use in Microsoft Windows, WINE, and possibly http://www.ReactOS.org/ since the Windows Registry is specific to a Microsoft environment).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this amazingly clear Microsoft Support article: [Command-line switches for Microsoft Office products](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6)  It lists executable names and paths for Office 2007, 2010, 2013, and 2016 products in its *Startup command names and locations* section .

I notice that the version of Windows 7/Office that I'm using now *does* list the target path in the shortcut, but I have run across this problem in the past.

Edit: I also discovered that this is because of .NET Advertised Shortcuts. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270779/why-is-the-target-disabled-in-dot-net-shortcuts-after-setup) gives a bit more info.